# Navigate to the​ JW Player SDK for Android .aar file Crashing the app #9

Tags: android, sdk, native, jwplayer

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-android-demo/issues/9

I tried this above github source code for JWPlayer android native app. But  without JWPlayerSDK, its not working it seems. I tried to contact JWplayer[ https://www.jwplayer.com/products/mobile-sdk/ ] sales team. I didnt get response properly. Can any one help regarding this,thanks.

I got this error :    License Edition INVALID is not valid for JW Player Android SDK.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jwplayer.opensourcedemo, PID: 1874
java.lang.AssertionError: License Edition INVALID is not valid for JW Player Android SDK.
at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.license.segmentation.b$1.run(SourceFile:82)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a mobile SDK license in order to implement JW Player in native apps. Free versions of the iOS and Android SDKs will be available this year. For an enterprise license, you should be able to contact: https://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/